# I have a problem with the slick slider in ionic4 .in slider when i apply position absolute to slick arrow main image does not appear

Tags: html, css, ionic4, slick.js

[image: .]

Here is my css code

css:

```
 ::ng-deep .slick-arrow {
   background-color: transparent;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
   width: 25px;
   height: 92px;
   outline: none;
   display: table;
   z-index: 111;
}
::ng-deep .slick-arrow img{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

when I remove position absolute image looks good but my arrows become unset.
Thank You in advance..

Comment: Where is your html? Paste your whole code so that we can debug.